# jQuery button click attr('src') returns Undefined

Tags: jquery

The images & ID for **img src** is dynamically generated by Jinja2 templates & the images are returned via a function.
So I'm looking to use the **$this** jquery option on **button** element to get the **img src.**
this is the jinja2 template code...

```
<div id="center-container" class="span9">
    {% for article_row in images | batch(3, '&nbsp;') %}
        <ul class="thumbnails">
        {% for article in article_row %}
            <li class="span3">

                <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src ="img/{{ article|e  }}" data-src="holder.js/360x270" alt="" id="img{{loop.index}}">

                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>{{ article }}</p>
                </div>
            <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button" id="img{{loop.index}}">Large button</button>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**This is the page src after rendered :**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
<div id="center-container" class="span9">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src ="img/allofthethings.png" data-src="holder.js/360x270" alt="" id="img1">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>allofthethings.png</p>
            </div>
        <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button" id="img1">Large button</button>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src ="img/brogrammer.jpg" data-src="holder.js/360x270" alt="" id="img2">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>brogrammer.jpg</p>
            </div>
        <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button" id="img2">Large button</button>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src ="img/couragewolf.jpg" data-src="holder.js/360x270" alt="" id="img3">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>couragewolf.jpg</p>
            </div>
        <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button" id="img3">Large button</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../inc/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</body>
```

This is where I get the error:
**js function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("button").click(function(){
        var src=$(this).attr("src");
        alert(src);
           alert($(this).attr('src'));
        console.log(src);
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not have 'src' attribute. Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").click(function(){
    var src=$(this).parent().find('img').attr('src');
    console.log(src);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ID's need to be unique,you seem to have same `ID` for button and img element, `$(this)` refers to `button`, and button do not have `src` attribute, so change:

```
var src=$(this).attr("src");
```

to

```
var src=$(this).parents("li.span3").find("img").attr("src");
```

Comment: Or, better, use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` refers to button which has no `src` attribute, Thus change your code as

```
var src=$(this).closest("li.span3").find("img").prop("src");
```

Instead of

```
var src=$(this).attr("src");
```

I would suggest you to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)